# How I can read file with Array in spark scala?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata

The interviewer asked me to read this file using spark-scala and select from this data, I don,t know which file contain this kind of data. I tried with csv but it shows error that csv does not support array type.

output required is -> 1,salman,p

file.csv data -

```
1,salman,[p, c, m]
2,srk,[p, c, b]
3,aamir, [p, c, g]

val schema1 = StructType(List(
    StructField("Id", IntegerType),
    StructField("Name", StringType),
    StructField("Subjects",ArrayType.apply(StringType))

val df1=spark.read
    .schema(schema1)
    .format("csv")
    .load("/home/sayyad/study_material/syllabus_ppt/file1.csv")
```

Comment: Try with StructField("Subjects", ArrayType(StringType)) instead of StructField("Subjects",ArrayType.apply(StringType))

checkout https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/dataframe-schema-structfield-structtype/

Comment: read as text file & split by `,` extract & filter required data.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
df1.select("Id", "Name", $"Subjects".getItem(0))
```